# Magento - Linux server DU (root) CPU spikes

Tags: magento-1.7, hosting, centos

I am concerned about my server as I am seeing consistent CPU spikes in New Relic caused by DU. I am not having much help from the hosting company as they keep saying it is an application problem (however I got a little bit hopeful yesterday when someone actually looked into my server and and saw my APC memory was full up as the setting was only at 38mb.)

They adjusted it to 128mb. Since then the site performance has noticeably improved and the site feels more snappy.

I have started to notice the CPU spikes again which are consistent but site performance feels fine. Again it seems to be caused by DU (I am site owner so my knowledge is limited) see screenshot:
[image: DU (Root) CPU SPIKES]

Here is an overview of the server over last 12 hours:

[image: Server overview 12 hours]

[image: Apc stats]

APC Stats

My server has 4gb ram and settings are as follows

PHP Memory - 2048mb
APC - 128mb

Here is a screenshot from Top command. 
[image]

And the new relic server graphs around time of Top screenshot

[image]

Here are my cron jobs:

[image]

Comment: Strange behavior. Do you have SSH access to go in and see some detail from top, etc?

Comment: Yes I do. The stats jump around alot so its hard to see exactly whats happening. I will try include a screenshot of TOP

Comment: Top stats keep jumping around. I can't seem to freeze it to capture activity.

Comment: Well, could it be related to a dashboard or monitoring of some kind, maybe installed by your hosting provider? I see Sensu running. Maybe it's polling du for information, though root is not a brilliant choice for running that. This is a dedicated server, correct?

Comment: No its cloud hosting.

Comment: Well then, your host is the only one who could try and explain what's going on, as there could be several things happening behind the scenes. If site performance is now fine, I wouldn't worry about it. Also, you can run one-shot top by running 'top -n 1' in case you ever need that again.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the Top command and an updated New relic screenshot around the time of the Top screenshot.

Comment: This question would be better placed on SuperUser - as it is unrelated to Magento.

Answer (score 3):

Its clearly a cron task, likely that of whatever server control panel you are using.

`du` is a Linux utility for calculating disk usage of a given directory/file/path.

You could try a quick grep through the cron tasks, but if you are using something like cPanel/Plesk - its unlikely the command itself is likely to embedded within the cronjob itself.

```
grep -r "du " /etc/cron* /var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

On Debian/Ubuntu, `/etc/cron.daily/apt` is a likely candidate.

If you use `ps ax | grep du` at the time the process is running, you'll see more information about the process/command.

Comment: Hi. I have added screenshot of cron jobs. Thanks